# Python Regex Match only lower case words between anything

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to catch all the eng words between any non word characters (just pure [a-z]+)

So this line:

> "你好" means "Hello" and "再见" is "See you".hello_me bye-you what6 58then end_of_this

would return:

> means, and, is, you, hello, me, bye, you, what, then, end, of, this

words may have any surroundings but for a-z

I have come up with this:

```
(?:[\s_\d\"\'-])?([a-z]+)(?:[-\s_\d\"\'])?
```

yet it matches 'ello' in Hello but i want to ignore non lower case words fully

also would be nice if a template design allows using ignore case flag then

```
(?i)(?:[\s_\d\"\'-])?([a-z]+)(?:[-\s_\d\"\'])?
```

to easily switch between lower case matches only and all of them

Comment: Use the `\b` word boundary pattern to match whole words.

Comment: The before and after has flaws. The question is a little flawed. `" is "See you".hello` does not become `is, you, hello`

Comment: @sln " i want to ignore non lower case words fully"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't appear to be difficult.
You've described a custom word boundary denoted by `(?<![a-zA-Z])` before
and `(?![a-zA-Z])` after.

`(?<![a-zA-Z])[a-z]+(?![a-zA-Z])`

Code sample

```
import re

s='"你好" means "Hello" and "再见" is "See you".hello_me bye-you what6 58then end_of_this'
print(re.findall(r'(?<![a-zA-Z])[a-z]+(?![a-zA-Z])', s))
```

Output

```
['means', 'and', 'is', 'you', 'hello', 'me', 'bye', 'you', 'what', 'then', 'end', 'of', 'this']
```

Comment: thanks works as needed those the negative way tho
(?<![^\W_\d])[a-z]+(?![^\W_\d])

Answer (score 1):

This works for the example.  Might be missing some edge case...

```py
import re

s='"你好" means "Hello" and "再见" is "See you".hello_me bye-you what6 58then end_of_this'
print(re.findall(r'(?:\b|[^A-Za-z]|(?<=_))([a-z]+)(?:\b|[^A-Za-z]|(?=_))', s))
```

Output:

```
['means', 'and', 'is', 'you', 'hello', 'me', 'bye', 'you', 'what', 'then', 'end', 'of', 'this']
```

Comment: I believe `(?:\b|[^A-Za-z]|(?<=_))` can be shortened as `(?<![A-Za-z])`.

Comment: was close never thought of lookahead/behind to be put inside the non capture